# Vectorised Marching cubes (squares) - connecting the lines into curves

Tags: python, algorithm

I am drawing a metaball with marching cubes (squares as it is a 2d) algorithm.
Everything is fine, but I  want to get it as a vector object.

So far I've got a vector line or two from each active  square, keeping them in list **lines**. In other words, I have an array of small vector lines, spatially displaying several isolines (curves) - my aim is to rebuild those curves back from lines.

Now I am stuck with fast joining them all together: basically I need to connect all lines one by one all together into several sequences (curves). I don't know how many curves (sequences) will be there, and lines could be in different directions and I need to process lines into sequences of unique points.

So far I wrote something obviously ugly and half-working (here **line** is a class with list of points as attribute **points**, and **chP** is a function checking if points are close enough, **t** definies this 'enough') :

```
def countur2(lines):

   '''transform random list of lines into 
   list of  grouped sequences'''
   t = 2 # tolerance

   sqnss = [[lines[0]]] # sequences
   kucha = [lines[0]] #list of already used lines

   for l in lines:
      for i,el in enumerate(lines):
          print 'working on el', i
          ss = sqnss[-1][0]
          ee = sqnss[-1][-1]
          if el not in kucha:
              if chP(el.points[0],ee.points[1],t):
                  sqnss[-1].append(el)
                  kucha.append(el)
                  break
              elif chP(el.points[1],ee.points[1],t):
                  sqnss[-1].append(el.rvrse())
                  kucha.append(el)
                  break

              elif chP(el.points[1],ss.points[0],t): 
                  sqnss[-1] = [el] + sqnss[-1]
                  kucha.append(el)
                  break

              elif chP(el.points[0],ss.points[0],t):
                  sqnss[-1] = [el.rvrse()] + sqnss[-1]
                  kucha.append(el)
                  break



          print 'new shape added, with el as start'
          sqnss.append([el])
          kucha.append(el)


   #return sqnse of points
   ps = []
   for x in sqnss: ps.append([el.points[0] for el in x])

   return ps
```

I know this is such a big question, but please give me any clue on right direction to handle this task

Answer (score 2):

A first option is to number all cell sides uniquely, and associate to every vector the pair of edges it joins.

Enter all pairs in a dictionary, both ways: `(a,b)` and `(b,a)`. Then, starting from an arbitrary pair, say `(a,b)`, you will find the next pair through `b`, say `(b,c)`. You will remove both `(b,c)` and `(c,b)` from the dictionary, and continue from `c`, until the chain breaks on a side of the domain, or loops.

A second option is to scan the whole domain and when you find a cell crossed by an isocurve, compute the vector, and move to the neighboring cell that shares an edge crossed by the isocurve, and so on. To avoid an infinite scanning, you will flag the cell as already visited.

By contrast with the first approach, no dictionary is required, as the following of the chain is purely based on the local geometry.

Beware that there are two traps:

- cells having one or more corner values equal to the iso-level are creating trouble. A possible cure is by slightly modifying the values corner; this will create a few tiny vectors.
- cells can be crossed by two vectors instead of one, and require to be visited twice.

Comment: what do you mean as a key in those dictionaries (solution 1) ?

Comment: @Casy_fill: Do you understand the linking process ?

Comment: @Casy_fill: then if you understand it, it should be clear the the dictionary keys are the edge numbers.

Comment: It would be a bit clearer if you said they are key-value pairs a->b and b->a.